# excel if statement 0 value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating an if statement which helps calculate the difference between two cells and displays the difference as a percentage- here's an example of the code I am using - =IF(D19=E19,"Values are accurate",(D19-E19)/E19)

the problems occurs when 'E19 is 0 and D19 has a value in it' it display a error in the cell that says '#DIV/0!' I no the error occurs because the 0 but I want my spread sheet to be consistent and display the percentage variances weather it be positive or negative.

can anybody help?

---

ok I understand that it would need a scale, but how do I determine the scale?.

To give you a picture of what I am doing; I am providing analysing stock; the first value (D19) id the quantity that is on the system, the second quantity (E19) is the physical stock. So there for therefore sometime the physical stock is sometimes a 0 value and that's where the problem occurs.

Comment: Mathematically you can't do this, how would you know the % change from zero when you don't have a basis? If this was an absolute scale like -50 to 50, you might be able to

Comment: What I'm saying is that if physical stock is at 0, then the increase or decrease can be defined in *units* rather than *percentage*. So you could, for instance, return "2 units" for something that started with 0, but you couldn't say what percentage that changed. See the additional text in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
=IF(D19=E19,"Values are accurate",(D19-E19)/MAX(D19:E19))
```

This scales your differences between -100% and +100%.
So, if you have 3 system stock and 1 physical, the value it will be +67% off (instead of +200% as by your previous formula). If you can live with that, this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like -

```
=IF(D19=E19,"accurate",IF(E19=0,magic formula,(D19-E19/E19))
```

But the magic formula will only work if you know, mathematically, that your scale is absolute.

For instance a change from 1 to 2 is 100% and -1 to -2 is -100%. But, from 0 to 1 is only a change of 10% if the scale is 0-100. If the scale is 0-3, it's 33%, etc

One magic formula you might be able to use would be `(-1)(E19-F19` to give you the number of units changed.

```
=if(D19=E19,"Values are accurate",IF(E19=0,(-1)(E19-F10)&" unit change",((D19-E19)/(E19))))
```